# My Auto-scaling Cloud-formation template is not working

Tags: json, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

    "Parameters": {
        "VpcId": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
            "Description": "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be the VPC Id of an existing Virtual Private Cloud."
        },
        "Subnets": {
            "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
            "Description": "The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)"
        },
        "InstanceType": {
            "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "t2.small",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "t1.micro",
                "t2.nano",
                "t2.micro",
                "t2.small",
                "t2.medium",
                "t2.large",
                "m1.small",
                "m1.medium",
                "cg1.4xlarge"
            ],
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
        },
"WebServerCapacity": {
      "Default": "2",
      "Description": "The initial number of WebServer instances",
      "Type": "Number",
      "MinValue": "1",
      "MaxValue": "10",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be between 1 and 10 EC2 instances."
    },
        "KeyName": {
            "Description": "The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instances",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
        },
        "SSHLocation": {
            "Description": "The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength": "9",
            "MaxLength": "18",
            "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
        }
    },

    "Resources": {
      "WebServerScaleUpPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": 1
            }
        },
        "WebServerScaleDownPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": -1
            }
        },
        "CPUAlarmHigh": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "AlarmDescription": "Scale-up if CPU > 70% for 5 minutes",
                "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                "Statistic": "Average",
                "Period": 300,
                "EvaluationPeriods": 2,
                "Threshold": 70,
                "AlarmActions": [{
                    "Ref": "WebServerScaleUpPolicy"
                }],
                "Dimensions": [{
                    "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                    "Value": {
                        "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                    }
                }],
                "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold"
            }
        },
        "CPUAlarmLow": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "AlarmDescription": "Scale-down if CPU < 40% for 5 minutes",
                "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                "Statistic": "Average",
                "Period": 300,
                "EvaluationPeriods": 2,
                "Threshold": 40,
                "AlarmActions": [{
                    "Ref": "WebServerScaleDownPolicy"
                }],
                "Dimensions": [{
                    "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                    "Value": {
                        "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                    }
                }],
                "ComparisonOperator": "LessThanThreshold"
            }
        },
           "ApplicationLoadBalancer": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties": {
            "Name": "elb-test",
            "Scheme": "internet-facing",
            "IpAddressType": "ipv4",
            "Type": "application",
                "Subnets": {
                    "Ref": "Subnets"
                }
            }
        },
        "ALBListener": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
            "Properties": {
                "DefaultActions": [{
                    "Type": "forward",
                    "TargetGroupArn": {
                        "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
                    }
                }],
                "LoadBalancerArn": {
                    "Ref": "ApplicationLoadBalancer"
                },
                "Port": 80,
                "Protocol": "HTTP"
            }
        },
        "ALBTargetGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "ELB-Group",
                "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 30,
                "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds": 5,
                "HealthyThresholdCount": 3,
                "Port": 80,
                "Protocol": "HTTP",
                "TargetType": "instance",
                "UnhealthyThresholdCount": 5,
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VpcId"
                }
            }
        },
        "WebServerGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "VPCZoneIdentifier": {
                    "Ref": "Subnets"
                },
                "HealthCheckGracePeriod": 300,
                "LaunchConfigurationName": {
                    "Ref": "LaunchConfig"
                },
                "MinSize": "1",
                "MaxSize": "8",
                    "DesiredCapacity": {
                  "Ref": "WebServerCapacity"
                },
                "TargetGroupARNs": [{
                    "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
                }]
            },
      "CreationPolicy": {
        "ResourceSignal": {
          "Timeout": "PT5M",
          "Count": {
            "Ref": "WebServerCapacity"
          }
        }
      },
      "UpdatePolicy": {
        "AutoScalingRollingUpdate": {
          "MinInstancesInService": 1,
          "MaxBatchSize": 1,
          "PauseTime": "PT5M",
          "WaitOnResourceSignals": true
        }
      }
        },
        "LaunchConfig": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Properties": {
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyName"
                },
                "ImageId": "ami-00932e4c143f3fdf0",
                "SecurityGroups": [{
                    "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"
                }],
                "InstanceType": {
                    "Ref": "InstanceType"
                },
                "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
             "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
             "apt-get update -y\n",
             "apt-get install -y python-setuptools\n",
             "mkdir -p /opt/aws/bin\n",
             "python /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy_install.py --script-dir /opt/aws/bin https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz\n",
              "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
             "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
             "         --resource EC2Instance ",
             "         --configsets full_install ",
             "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",

             "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
             "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
             "         --resource EC2Instance ",
             "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
            ]]}}}
            },
        
        
        "InstanceSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "Enable SSH access and HTTP from the load balancer only",
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [{
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": 22,
                        "ToPort": 22,
                        "CidrIp": {
                            "Ref": "SSHLocation"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": 80,
                        "ToPort": 80,
                        "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
                            "Fn::Select": [
                                0,
                                {
                                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                        "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                                        "SecurityGroups"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VpcId"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "URL": {
            "Description": "The URL of the website",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                        "http://",
                        {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                                "DNSName"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this template to create auto-scaling with cloud formation and i am using ubuntu-18.04. Every time I am getting same error.
Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
Failed to receive 1 resource signal(s) for the current batch. Each resource signal timeout is counted as a FAILURE.
Please let me know where i am lacking

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Could you expand? :)

Comment: When I started this after few seconds I got this :- The following resource(s) failed to create: [ALBTargetGroup, ApplicationLoadBalancer]. . Rollback requested by user.  (ROLLBACK_COMPLETE)

Comment: There should be some more error messages in addition, try to look for the first one to trigger

Comment: No there is no more error on that
When I clicked start after few seconds it will Delete and Rollback everything. So could please check if there is any issue with this template ?

Comment: I'll give it a run now

Answer (score 1):

I have ran your template through [cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) and got a lot of problems reported:

```
W2030 You must specify a valid allowed value for InstanceType (cg1.4xlarge).
Valid values are ['a1.2xlarge', 'a1.4xlarge', 'a1.large', 'a1.medium', 'a1.metal', 'a1.xlarge', 'c1.medium', 'c1.xlarge', 'c3.2xlarge', 'c3.4xlarge', 'c3.8xlarge', 'c3.large', 'c3.xlarge', 'c4.2xlarge', 'c4.4xlarge', 'c4.8xlarge', 'c4.large', 'c4.xlarge', 'c5.12xlarge', 'c5.18xlarge', 'c5.24xlarge', 'c5.2xlarge', 'c5.4xlarge', 'c5.9xlarge', 'c5.large', 'c5.metal', 'c5.xlarge', 'c5d.12xlarge', 'c5d.18xlarge', 'c5d.24xlarge', 'c5d.2xlarge', 'c5d.4xlarge', 'c5d.9xlarge', 'c5d.large', 'c5d.metal', 'c5d.xlarge', 'c5n.18xlarge', 'c5n.2xlarge', 'c5n.4xlarge', 'c5n.9xlarge', 'c5n.large', 'c5n.metal', 'c5n.xlarge', 'cc2.8xlarge', 'cr1.8xlarge', 'd2.2xlarge', 'd2.4xlarge', 'd2.8xlarge', 'd2.xlarge', 'f1.16xlarge', 'f1.2xlarge', 'f1.4xlarge', 'g2.2xlarge', 'g2.8xlarge', 'g3.16xlarge', 'g3.4xlarge', 'g3.8xlarge', 'g3s.xlarge', 'g4dn.12xlarge', 'g4dn.16xlarge', 'g4dn.2xlarge', 'g4dn.4xlarge', 'g4dn.8xlarge', 'g4dn.metal', 'g4dn.xlarge', 'h1.16xlarge', 'h1.2xlarge', 'h1.4xlarge', 'h1.8xlarge', 'hs1.8xlarge', 'i2.2xlarge', 'i2.4xlarge', 'i2.8xlarge', 'i2.xlarge', 'i3.16xlarge', 'i3.2xlarge', 'i3.4xlarge', 'i3.8xlarge', 'i3.large', 'i3.metal', 'i3.xlarge', 'i3en.12xlarge', 'i3en.24xlarge', 'i3en.2xlarge', 'i3en.3xlarge', 'i3en.6xlarge', 'i3en.large', 'i3en.metal', 'i3en.xlarge', 'm1.large', 'm1.medium', 'm1.small', 'm1.xlarge', 'm2.2xlarge', 'm2.4xlarge', 'm2.xlarge', 'm3.2xlarge', 'm3.large', 'm3.medium', 'm3.xlarge', 'm4.10xlarge', 'm4.16xlarge', 'm4.2xlarge', 'm4.4xlarge', 'm4.large', 'm4.xlarge', 'm5.12xlarge', 'm5.16xlarge', 'm5.24xlarge', 'm5.2xlarge', 'm5.4xlarge', 'm5.8xlarge', 'm5.large', 'm5.metal', 'm5.xlarge', 'm5a.12xlarge', 'm5a.16xlarge', 'm5a.24xlarge', 'm5a.2xlarge', 'm5a.4xlarge', 'm5a.8xlarge', 'm5a.large', 'm5a.xlarge', 'm5ad.12xlarge', 'm5ad.24xlarge', 'm5ad.2xlarge', 'm5ad.4xlarge', 'm5ad.large', 'm5ad.xlarge', 'm5d.12xlarge', 'm5d.16xlarge', 'm5d.24xlarge', 'm5d.2xlarge', 'm5d.4xlarge', 'm5d.8xlarge', 'm5d.large', 'm5d.metal', 'm5d.xlarge', 'm5dn.12xlarge', 'm5dn.16xlarge', 'm5dn.24xlarge', 'm5dn.2xlarge', 'm5dn.4xlarge', 'm5dn.8xlarge', 'm5dn.large', 'm5dn.metal', 'm5dn.xlarge', 'm5n.12xlarge', 'm5n.16xlarge', 'm5n.24xlarge', 'm5n.2xlarge', 'm5n.4xlarge', 'm5n.8xlarge', 'm5n.large', 'm5n.metal', 'm5n.xlarge', 'p2.16xlarge', 'p2.8xlarge', 'p2.xlarge', 'p3.16xlarge', 'p3.2xlarge', 'p3.8xlarge', 'p3dn.24xlarge', 'r3.2xlarge', 'r3.4xlarge', 'r3.8xlarge', 'r3.large', 'r3.xlarge', 'r4.16xlarge', 'r4.2xlarge', 'r4.4xlarge', 'r4.8xlarge', 'r4.large', 'r4.xlarge', 'r5.12xlarge', 'r5.16xlarge', 'r5.24xlarge', 'r5.2xlarge', 'r5.4xlarge', 'r5.8xlarge', 'r5.large', 'r5.metal', 'r5.xlarge', 'r5a.12xlarge', 'r5a.16xlarge', 'r5a.24xlarge', 'r5a.2xlarge', 'r5a.4xlarge', 'r5a.8xlarge', 'r5a.large', 'r5a.xlarge', 'r5ad.12xlarge', 'r5ad.24xlarge', 'r5ad.2xlarge', 'r5ad.4xlarge', 'r5ad.large', 'r5ad.xlarge', 'r5d.12xlarge', 'r5d.16xlarge', 'r5d.24xlarge', 'r5d.2xlarge', 'r5d.4xlarge', 'r5d.8xlarge', 'r5d.large', 'r5d.metal', 'r5d.xlarge', 'r5dn.12xlarge', 'r5dn.16xlarge', 'r5dn.24xlarge', 'r5dn.2xlarge', 'r5dn.4xlarge', 'r5dn.8xlarge', 'r5dn.large', 'r5dn.metal', 'r5dn.xlarge', 'r5n.12xlarge', 'r5n.16xlarge', 'r5n.24xlarge', 'r5n.2xlarge', 'r5n.4xlarge', 'r5n.8xlarge', 'r5n.large', 'r5n.metal', 'r5n.xlarge', 't1.micro', 't2.2xlarge', 't2.large', 't2.medium', 't2.micro', 't2.nano', 't2.small', 't2.xlarge', 't3.2xlarge', 't3.large', 't3.medium', 't3.micro', 't3.nano', 't3.small', 't3.xlarge', 't3a.2xlarge', 't3a.large', 't3a.medium', 't3a.micro', 't3a.nano', 't3a.small', 't3a.xlarge', 'u-18tb1.metal', 'u-24tb1.metal', 'x1.16xlarge', 'x1.32xlarge', 'x1e.16xlarge', 'x1e.2xlarge', 'x1e.32xlarge', 'x1e.4xlarge', 'x1e.8xlarge', 'x1e.xlarge', 'z1d.12xlarge', 'z1d.2xlarge', 'z1d.3xlarge', 'z1d.6xlarge', 'z1d.large', 'z1d.metal', 'z1d.xlarge']
so.template:27:17

W7001 Mapping 'AWSInstanceType2Arch' is defined but not used
so.template:55:9

W7001 Mapping 'AWSInstanceType2NATArch' is defined but not used
so.template:87:9

E3012 Property Resources/WebServerScaleUpPolicy/Properties/ScalingAdjustment should be of type Integer
so.template:120:17

E3012 Property Resources/WebServerScaleDownPolicy/Properties/ScalingAdjustment should be of type Integer
so.template:131:17

E3012 Property Resources/CPUAlarmHigh/Properties/Period should be of type Integer
so.template:141:17

E3012 Property Resources/CPUAlarmHigh/Properties/EvaluationPeriods should be of type Integer
so.template:142:17

E3012 Property Resources/CPUAlarmHigh/Properties/Threshold should be of type Double
so.template:143:17

E3012 Property Resources/CPUAlarmLow/Properties/Period should be of type Integer
so.template:163:17

E3012 Property Resources/CPUAlarmLow/Properties/EvaluationPeriods should be of type Integer
so.template:164:17

E3012 Property Resources/CPUAlarmLow/Properties/Threshold should be of type Double
so.template:165:17

E3012 Property Resources/ALBListener/Properties/Port should be of type Integer
so.template:202:17

E3002 Invalid Property Resources/ALBTargetGroup/Properties/HealthCheckType
so.template:217:17

E3016 Value for MinInstancesInService must be of type Integer
so.template:251:11

E3016 Value for MaxBatchSize must be of type Integer
so.template:252:11

E3016 Value for WaitOnResourceSignals must be of type Boolean
so.template:254:11

E3012 Property Resources/InstanceSecurityGroup/Properties/SecurityGroupIngress/0/FromPort should be of type Integer
so.template:280:25

E3012 Property Resources/InstanceSecurityGroup/Properties/SecurityGroupIngress/0/ToPort should be of type Integer
so.template:281:25

E3012 Property Resources/InstanceSecurityGroup/Properties/SecurityGroupIngress/1/FromPort should be of type Integer
so.template:288:25

E3012 Property Resources/InstanceSecurityGroup/Properties/SecurityGroupIngress/1/ToPort should be of type Integer
so.template:289:25
```

I'd suggest you fix these issues first.

Comment: Hi Lexicore
Is it important to run cfn code while creating auto-scaling with cloud-formation on ubuntu 18.04 or is there any other alternative ??

Comment: @shubhamkamboj It is not mandatory but highly recommended. There are issues with your template and you need to fix them.

Comment: Threshold should be of type Double -  Please explain this right now I am using this 
"Threshold": "40", So shoul use like "Threshold": 40,
or what?

Comment: i made changes in this template please have a look and let me know

Comment: @shubhamkamboj How about you install cfn-lint and check your templates on your own? Here's what I've got for the current version:
https://pastebin.com/fQhsrGDc
But I won't do this again for you, sorry.

Comment: @shubhamkamboj Yes, I'd try `40` instead of `"40"` but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: this cfn is not working in my case could you please recommend alternative of this?

Comment: @shubhamkamboj I am not aware of any alternatives. Except endlessly trying templates in CF online.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming down to `HealthCheckType` being in the target group resource, it should instead be attached to your autoscaling group.

The fixed template for this error is below

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

    "Parameters": {
        "VpcId": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
            "Description": "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be the VPC Id of an existing Virtual Private Cloud."
        },
        "Subnets": {
            "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
            "Description": "The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)"
        },
        "InstanceType": {
            "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "t2.small",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "t1.micro",
                "t2.nano",
                "t2.micro",
                "t2.small",
                "t2.medium",
                "t2.large",
                "m1.small",
                "m1.medium",
                "cg1.4xlarge"
            ],
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
        },
"WebServerCapacity": {
      "Default": "2",
      "Description": "The initial number of WebServer instances",
      "Type": "Number",
      "MinValue": "1",
      "MaxValue": "10",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be between 1 and 10 EC2 instances."
    },
        "KeyName": {
            "Description": "The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instances",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
        },
        "SSHLocation": {
            "Description": "The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength": "9",
            "MaxLength": "18",
            "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
            "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
            "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
        }
    },
    "Mappings": {
        "AWSInstanceType2Arch": {
            "t1.micro": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "t2.nano": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "t2.micro": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "t2.small": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "t2.medium": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "t2.large": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "m1.small": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "m1.medium": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "m1.large": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            },
            "d2.xlarge": {
                "Arch": "HVM64"
            }
        },
        "AWSInstanceType2NATArch": {
            "t1.micro": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "t2.nano": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "t2.micro": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "t2.small": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "t2.medium": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "t2.large": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            },
            "m1.small": {
                "Arch": "NATHVM64"
            }
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
      "WebServerScaleUpPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": "1"
            }
        },
        "WebServerScaleDownPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
            "Properties": {
                "AdjustmentType": "ChangeInCapacity",
                "AutoScalingGroupName": {
                    "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                },
                "Cooldown": "60",
                "ScalingAdjustment": "-1"
            }
        },
        "CPUAlarmHigh": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "AlarmDescription": "Scale-up if CPU > 70% for 5 minutes",
                "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                "Statistic": "Average",
                "Period": "300",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
                "Threshold": "70",
                "AlarmActions": [{
                    "Ref": "WebServerScaleUpPolicy"
                }],
                "Dimensions": [{
                    "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                    "Value": {
                        "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                    }
                }],
                "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold"
            }
        },
        "CPUAlarmLow": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm",
            "Properties": {
                "AlarmDescription": "Scale-down if CPU < 40% for 5 minutes",
                "MetricName": "CPUUtilization",
                "Namespace": "AWS/EC2",
                "Statistic": "Average",
                "Period": "300",
                "EvaluationPeriods": "2",
                "Threshold": "40",
                "AlarmActions": [{
                    "Ref": "WebServerScaleDownPolicy"
                }],
                "Dimensions": [{
                    "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                    "Value": {
                        "Ref": "WebServerGroup"
                    }
                }],
                "ComparisonOperator": "LessThanThreshold"
            }
        },
                "ApplicationLoadBalancer": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties": {
            "Name": "elb-test",
            "Scheme": "internet-facing",
            "IpAddressType": "ipv4",
            "Type": "application",
                "Subnets": {
                    "Ref": "Subnets"
                }
            }
        },
        "ALBListener": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
            "Properties": {
                "DefaultActions": [{
                    "Type": "forward",
                    "TargetGroupArn": {
                        "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
                    }
                }],
                "LoadBalancerArn": {
                    "Ref": "ApplicationLoadBalancer"
                },
                "Port": "80",
                "Protocol": "HTTP"
            }
        },
        "ALBTargetGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "ELB-Group",
                "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds": 30,
                "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds": 5,
                "HealthyThresholdCount": 3,
                "Port": 80,
                "Protocol": "HTTP",
                "TargetType": "instance",
                "UnhealthyThresholdCount": 5,
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VpcId"
                }
            }
        },
        "WebServerGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "VPCZoneIdentifier": {
                    "Ref": "Subnets"
                },
                "HealthCheckType": "ELB",
                "HealthCheckGracePeriod": 300
                "LaunchConfigurationName": {
                    "Ref": "LaunchConfig"
                },
                "MinSize": "1",
                "MaxSize": "8",
                    "DesiredCapacity": {
                  "Ref": "WebServerCapacity"
                },
                "TargetGroupARNs": [{
                    "Ref": "ALBTargetGroup"
                }]
            },
      "CreationPolicy": {
        "ResourceSignal": {
          "Timeout": "PT5M",
          "Count": {
            "Ref": "WebServerCapacity"
          }
        }
      },
      "UpdatePolicy": {
        "AutoScalingRollingUpdate": {
          "MinInstancesInService": "1",
          "MaxBatchSize": "1",
          "PauseTime": "PT5M",
          "WaitOnResourceSignals": "true"
        }
      }
        },
        "LaunchConfig": {
            "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
            "Properties": {
                "KeyName": {
                    "Ref": "KeyName"
                },
                "ImageId": "ami-00932e4c143f3fdf0",
                "SecurityGroups": [{
                    "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup"
                }],
                "InstanceType": {
                    "Ref": "InstanceType"
                },
                "UserData": {
                    "Fn::Base64": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "#!/bin/bash -x\n",
                                "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
                                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                                "         --stack ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                                },
                                "         --resource MyInstance ",
                                "         --region ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                },
                                "\n",
                                "# Signal the status from cfn-init\n",
                                "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                                "         --stack ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                                },
                                "         --resource MyInstance ",
                                "         --region ",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                                },
                                "\n"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        
        "InstanceSecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupDescription": "Enable SSH access and HTTP from the load balancer only",
                "SecurityGroupIngress": [{
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "22",
                        "ToPort": "22",
                        "CidrIp": {
                            "Ref": "SSHLocation"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                        "FromPort": "80",
                        "ToPort": "80",
                        "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
                            "Fn::Select": [
                                0,
                                {
                                    "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                        "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                                        "SecurityGroups"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "VpcId": {
                    "Ref": "VpcId"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "URL": {
            "Description": "The URL of the website",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                        "http://",
                        {
                            "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                "ApplicationLoadBalancer",
                                "DNSName"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After Using this template Got this error
HealthCheckGracePeriod must be specified for ElasticLoadBalancer based health checks. (Service: AmazonAutoScaling; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: 0cf63a91-88ee-47b1-b5f4-49d08651fb77)

Comment: Updated the template, set it as a 300 second timeout

Comment: Now It is working fine but after some time it show an error 
Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
The following resource(s) failed to create: [WebServerGroup]. . Rollback requested by user.

and start processing the Rollback deleted

Comment: This is because you're using `WaitOnResourceSignals`. For this you need to make sure your instances send a signal to CloudFormation back. Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html

Comment: Hi Chris Could you please make that changes in this template.?

Comment: Do you want to give that a try now?

Comment: Yes i want to try this right now and as I am using ubuntu so please do this accordingly 
It will be really appreciate

Comment: Have you tested it on ubuntu?

Comment: Let me know if that work on this template please go through this:- 
https://gist.github.com/kixorz/10194688